# Node.js runinng scripts coherently

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some .js file, with names 1.js, 2.js etc. I want run it with node 1.js, node 2.js coherently (waiting for each script end it's work). How can  I run them with only 1 command? For Example "node all"?

Comment: This isn't a feature Node itself has. Your operating system and/or command shell almost certainly does, though. What operating system are you using? How do you want to run these scripts?

Comment: I use mac os, every script perform async task (loop requests) with exporting .json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've said you're using Mac OS X. If you're doing this in a command shell (which is `bash`), you can use `&&`:

```
node 1.js && node 2.js
```

The second command will wait for the first to complete before running, and `node` won't exit until in-progress async work in the script is complete.